# Нужно ли обособлять оборот "переодеваясь вчера", то есть ставить запятую после "что"?

Tags: запятые, деепричастный-оборот

*И только несколько секунд спустя до нее дошло, что переодеваясь вчера, она так и оставила свой кинжал валяться на стуле.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятая нужна, потому что ДО вклинивается в придаточное *"что она так и оставила свой кинжал валяться на стуле".* "Что" относится к "она", а не к "переодеваясь".